# Is there a way to delete a Material by name from a Python script?

Tags: python, materials

I have a script in which I read an FBX File in and replace the input material with a Blender material. The old FBX material remains in the scene tough until the file is closed.
I have the name of the old material but I can't find a way to remove it from the file right after the conversion.
In the Blender UI, in the Object Lister -> Blender File section I can delete any material immediately out of the file. (Unfortunately the Information Window doesn't show any meaningful code to this operation.)
Is there a way to do the same from within Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get your material, for instance

```
 m = bpy.data.materials['Material.001']
```

Then remove it

```
 bpy.data.materials.remove(m)
```

You can also check if `m.users` is 0 to be sure the material is not in use somewhere.

Comment: Oh, that was simple. Thanks!